# Cant use get_chart function in blockchain python client

Tags: python, blockchain.info-api

Trying to run

```py
import blockchain
from blockchain import statistics

get_chart(chart_type="mempool-size", time_span="1year")
```

Gives a function not defined error, despite `get_chart` being defined in the `statistics.py` file for the `blockchain.info` client. How can I run the `get_chart` function?

Does anyone have any troubleshooting ideas? Question has been up for a couple days and I'm stuck. I've checked the GitHub repo for issues and can't find any, haven't tried anything else yet as I'm unsure where to start.

I'm happy with any python solution that can get chart data from https://blockchain.info

Comment: Try calling it as `statistics.get_chart(chart_type="mempool-size", time_span="1year")` and it should work. Alternatively, you can do the import as `from blockchain.statistics import get_chart` and then leave the call the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `get_chart` is defined in `blockchain.statistics`, but importing the `statistics` module does bring its members into the global namespace. You have to dot off of it to access its members, such as `get_chart`:

```py
from blockchain import statistics

statistics.get_chart(chart_type="mempool-size", time_span="1year")
```

Alternatively you can import the function directly:

```py
from blockchain.statistics import get_chart

get_chart(chart_type="mempool-size", time_span="1year")
```

---

Unfortunately that won't solve the larger issue at hand which is that the repository for the package appears to be abandoned. For your request it tries to access data from the URL `https://blockchain.info/charts/mempool-size?format=json&timespan=1year`, which results it in downloading an HTML page instead of JSON.

Still, you can access the charts API using the docs provided here: https://www.blockchain.com/api/charts_api

For your request the correct URL to use is: `https://api.blockchain.info/charts/mempool-size?format=json&timespan=1year`

You can download it and parse the JSON into a dictionary like so:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://api.blockchain.info/charts/mempool-size?format=json&timespan=1year'
data = json.loads(urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: despite fixing my no-dotting mistake and using code as you have written above,  I'm getting  JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), regardless of which chart or timespan I request. Any way to fix this? would you check to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @EliBain I have updated the answer. Hopefully that will help.